# javax swing - creating windows

Tags: java, swing, console

I am a beginner in Java & I am learning the swing api.  I am having trouble with my code, and I can't figure out how to fix it.  Please help.

**Below is an example of the code I am using:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HelloWorldApp extends JFrame {


  public static void main(String args[]) {

    CustomWindow w = new CustomWindow();
    w.setVisible(true);

  }

  public CustomWindow() {

    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Jacob Perkins");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World!");
    add(lbl);

  }

}
```

My problem is that I get the following error:

```
invalid method declaration; return type required
```

Comment: You need a Java-tutorial to understand, what is constructor. method and other OO stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public CustomWindow() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Jacob Perkins");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World!");
    add(lbl);
}
```

should be:

```
public void CustomWindow() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Jacob Perkins");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World!");
    add(lbl);
}
```

Or instead of `void` (for returning nothing) we would put the data type we wanted to return. The method would now have to include a `return` statement which returns an appropriate data type to match the method signature, or you will get the error you have:

> invalid method declaration; return type required

See [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Unless you are attempting to create a constructor for the `HelloWorldApp` class than the method must be given the class name (have a read on [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)):

```
public HelloWorldApp() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setTitle("Jacob Perkins");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World!");
    add(lbl);
 }
```

**Other suggestions**

- Dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily.
- Dont call `setSize` rather use correct `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize` and return `Dimension`s which fit its contents. Than call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible but after adding components.
- Create and manipulate Swing components on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block:

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          //create and show ui here
          CustomWindow w = new CustomWindow();
          w.setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I'm just a beginner and don't really know what SwingUtilities.invokeLater() does.

Comment: @JaPerk14 see my update...and click on  `Event Dispatch Thread` it will link you to the Java concurrency lesson which should tell you all you need to know

Comment: The code example above where you are calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), would you run this in the public static void main(String args[])?

Comment: @JaPerk14 yup, the `SwingUtiltites` will just make sure our UI components are created on the event dispatcher thread

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
public CustomWindow() {
```

as written needs a return type (`void` is appropriate if you're not returning anything). However, this is evidently meant to be a constructor; if that's the case, it needs to be named the same as the class it's in. You'll need to either rename it to `HelloWorldApp` or rename the class to `CustomWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java File name must match classes they are implementing. So you need to either change your class and filename to CustomWindow or change the name of your constructor to HelloWorldApp():

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

 public class HelloWorldApp extends JFrame {


public static void main(String args[]) {

  HelloWorldApp w = new HelloWorldApp();
  w.setVisible(true);

 }
 public HelloWorldApp() {

   setSize(500, 500);
   setTitle("Jacob Perkins");
   JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World!");
   add(lbl);

 }

 }
```